# Get Strings from bpl package

Tags: delphi

sorry this may be a simple question

i want to call a bpl and get the value of a string inside the pakage

where and how can i declare a constant(or variable) and how to call it by a delphi exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the string constant is declared in the interface section of one of your units, you can just refer to it by name, the same as if the unit was compiled directly into your app.

Comment: Assuming it's in a statically linked package

Comment: Yeah.  Otherwise, you're probably using some sort of plugin system, and you'll need an API for retrieving data as a part of the plugin framework.